# Integrating Datalog with C++ applications

Tags: prolog, datomic, datalog

I'm not new to programming, but I am new to Datalog. I practiced Datalog throughout the week and it is very useful to make queries against a database. One thing I am having difficulties figuring out is how to use Datalog with a C++ application.

What I'm looking to do is, for example, take a user input as a dollar amount and run a query with that number to see if the dollar amount is less than the dollar amount for a fact in the database. This can be done with a rule possibly.

So far, I have not seen any way to integrate Datalog with C++ applications. As a beginner to Datalog integration, how do I setup my program to make datalog queries and such?

Comment: see non-jvm langauges: http://docs.datomic.com/languages.html

Comment: I saw that page a while ago, but I'm not sure if it works for what I'm trying to do. The REST service works via HTTP, which I doubt will work on custom devices that do not have this protocol, such as handheld diagnostic devices.

Comment: @bladematthewslp I assume you're using Datomic? (even though you didn't mention it in your post, you tagged your post with it). If that's the case, please read http://www.datomic.com/overview.html because as Valentin mentioned, HTTP would be the only way to do it (and you would still need to implement Datomic's HTTP API on your handheld diagnostic device) just like other non-jvm Datomic clients have done.